# Control android from windows

Tags: android

Is there any app, root access available to control android devices from windows, like

1. lock
2. show a notificaton
3. view the screen of the device

And the app should be up at all time, kinda like a spy app, but there is no sneaking here.
It would be really nice to stay away from google-related apps. I just remove all google things on those devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy)

Good thing is free and is cross platform across windows, Linux and MacOS

Answer (score 0):

here are the options you have for it. Choose the best for your need.

https://fossbytes.com/android-screen-mirroring-apps-pc/